# How to add id to textbox with Html.EditorFor statement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

I try to add id to textbox but get error. I should use `Html.EditorFor()` statement.Please advice.

My code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Historicals.HistoricalName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }, new { id = "Historical_place_name" })
```

Comment: It need to be `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Historicals.HistoricalName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Historical_place_name"} })`

Comment: But what is wrong with using the `id` that is already added by the `EditorFor()` method? (which is `id="Historicals_HistoricalName"`)

Comment: I use id for set style of lable and textbox in bootstrap.

Comment: So just use the default `id` value (which is `Historicals_HistoricalName`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should add the id property to the html attributes.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Historicals.HistoricalName, 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Historical_place_name" } });
```

Comment: Please delete  "  , null  "